# awk cmd to capture the line from STDOUT

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, awk

Following is the output of `gem environment` command.

```
○ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global
     - .bundle
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/"]
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
userme at userme in ~
```

What would be the `awk` command to capture the line `/Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global` under `- GEM PATHS:` striping the `-` just before the `/Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/- GEM PATHS:/ { N; s/.* - //p }' file
```

And another way using `awk`, if you're familiar with the use of  `getline`:

```
awk '/- GEM PATHS:/ { getline; sub(/.* - /,""); print }' file
```

Otherwise, this is probably you're safest bet:

```
awk 'n && !--n { sub(/.* - /,""); print } /- GEM PATHS:/ { n = 1 }' file
```

Results:

```
/Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global
```

Comment: +1 for the non-getline awk solution, but be aware that the getline solution will behave undesirably if the pattern you want is at the end of the file (and probably in some other situations).

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$ gem env gempath
/home/mpapis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286:/home/mpapis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global
```

it will display all the paths separated with PATH_SEPARATOR which is `:` on linux

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`, you can pipe the output through:

```
awk '{if(e){sub (/^ *- */,"",$0);print;e=0}}/GEM PATHS/{e=1}'
```

It works as follows:

- The `e` (echo) flag starts as 0 so echoing is disabled.
- For every line where the echo flag is set, it first removes the `<spaces>-<spaces>` at the start of the line, echoes the modified line, then resets the flag.
- Where it finds a `GEM PATHS` line, it sets the flag so that the next line is output using the previous rule.

Here's a small transcript of this in action:

```
pax> echo 'RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global
     - .bundle
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
' | awk '{if(e){sub (/^ *- */,"",$0);print;e=0}}/GEM PATHS/{e=1}'
```

```
/Users/userme/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/gemsets/global
```

Comment: No need for the `,$0` arg for sub() as that's the default. Also it'd be more awk-ish if you moved the test on "e" into the condition part of the script instead of wrapping it in an if clause within the action part of the script, i.e. `e{foo}` instead of `{if(e){foo}}`.